# Jitpack: Failed to resolve with Example Library (Android Studio)

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle, jitpack

I can't import any library using jitpack. My problem is with my own library, but below `com.github.jitpack:android-example:1.0.4` is used as an example library provided by jitpack itself that should have worked out of the box. Also note that offline stuff are off in android studio.

#### Root build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { 
            name "jitpack"
            url "https://jitpack.io" 
        }
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

#### App build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.me.stuff"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.4"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    // etc...
    implementation 'com.github.jitpack:android-example:1.0.4'
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        //force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    }
}
```

#### Error messages

Android studio shows:

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.github.jitpack:android-example:1.0.4
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app
```

Running gradle from the command line shows:

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.github.jitpack:android-example:1.0.4.
  Searched in the following locations:
      // A LOT OF IRRELEVANT LOCAL LOCATIONS OMITTED
      https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/jitpack/android-example/1.0.4/android-example-1.0.4.pom
      https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/jitpack/android-example/1.0.4/android-example-1.0.4.jar
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/jitpack/android-example/1.0.4/android-example-1.0.4.pom
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/jitpack/android-example/1.0.4/android-example-1.0.4.jar
      https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/jitpack/android-example/1.0.4/android-example-1.0.4.pom
      https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/jitpack/android-example/1.0.4/android-example-1.0.4.jar
      https://jitpack.io/com/github/jitpack/android-example/1.0.4/android-example-1.0.4.pom
      https://jitpack.io/com/github/jitpack/android-example/1.0.4/android-example-1.0.4.jar
```

Comment: can you try jitpack library with version 2.0 ?

Comment: `https://jitpack.io/com/github/jitpack/android-example/2.0/android-example-2.0.pom` is working means 2.0 version is there on jitpack

Comment: Also add the same jitpack maven url to buildScript block of your parent gradle file.

Comment: @RahulKumar It worked with 2.0! So that means the problem is with my library. Can you take a look at it: [github link](https://github.com/dboun/sticky-headers-recyclerview-androidx).

Comment: @RahulKumar I try to import it using: ```implementation 'com.github.dboun.sticky-headers-recyclerview-androidx:library:0.5.0'```

Comment: if you go to https://jitpack.io/#dboun/sticky-headers-recyclerview-androidx/0.5.0, you will find that you need to use `implementation 'com.github.dboun:sticky-headers-recyclerview-androidx:0.5.0'` (library: is not needed)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at https://jitpack.io/#jitpack/android-example or https://jitpack.io/com/github/jitpack/android-example/1.0.4/android-example-1.0.4.pom directly, you'll find that:

> Build failed. See the log at jitpack.io

Therefore the artifact is not available for download. More details you'll find in the *build.log* at https://jitpack.io/com/github/jitpack/android-example/1.0.4/build.log.

Use version 1.0.3 or 2.0 to continue with your experiments. For your own artifacts you'll find the issue when you look at your own *build.log* and if you cannot figure out what's wrong, you could as well open an issue on https://github.com/jitpack/jitpack.io/issues.